# How to insert values into database the right way?

Tags: php, mysql

For the last 5 hours I've been trying to figure out why this form won't insert data into MySQL when it seems to be correct.

**Form**

```
<form action="insertComment.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $article_uid;?>">

    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required/>
    <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Join the discussion..." required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Comment"/>

</form>
```

then on comment.php

```
include '../../../libraries/phpClass/commentClass.php';

$commentClass = new commentClass();

if(isset($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['comment']) AND isset($_POST['article_id']))
{
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $comment    = $_POST['comment'];
    $article_id = $_POST['article_id'];

    $data = $commentClass->insertComment($name, $email, $comment, $article_id);
}
```

and this is the public function..

```
public function insertComment($name, $email, $comment, $article_id)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO articles_comment(name, email, comment, article_id) VALUES (:name, :email, :comment, :article_id)");

    $sth->execute(array(
        ':name' => $name, 
        ':email' => $email, 
        ':comment' => $comment, 
        ':article_id' => $article_id
    ));  
}
```

from what I can see there isn't anything wrong and I haven't been able to see anything why it wouldn't insert the values.. there are no errors whatsoever either..

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` on the returned result of that `execute` call? It might just be returning false...

Comment: I am using PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION for the errors.

Comment: @iBrazilian2 Hurray! Now, can you verify that `insertComment` *is* being called? And, are any Transactions being used?

Comment: From what I tested, the insertComment isn't even being called because the $_POSt isn't even being set apparently, but as I mentioned I really don't see any errors on the form itself.

Comment: I tried doing it from the comment page without setting an action and it returns this.. object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(108) "INSERT INTO articles_comment(name, email, comment, article_id) VALUES (:name, :email, :comment, :article_id)"
}

Comment: I think you need a space after the table name, so your query would be more like : "INSERT INTO articles_comment (name, email, comment, article_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"

If not it could also be a problem with the database, what's the table structure look like ?